# C# - Access Database: Why SELECT * FROM table is not working?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

A simple "**select * from tablename**" sql query works for a table named 'mode' but not for a table named 'user'. Why?

Both tables have 2 columns. If I run the program with the "mySQL" variable as "SELECT * FROM mode" it works fine. If I put the user table instead, which means the mySQL would have been "SELECT * FROM user" then it raises an exception which says "Syntax error in FROM clause.". How can this be?

Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Accounts.mdb";
        OleDbConnection conn;
        conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.Write("Could not connect to database");
        }
        String mySQL = "SELECT * FROM user";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, conn);

        OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Console.Write(String.Format("{0}\n,{1}\n", rdr.GetValue(0).ToString(), rdr.GetValue(1).ToString()));
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Any exception on console?

Answer (score 4):

Because USER is a [reserved word in MS-Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?CorrelationId=4499dc9c-f60c-4d19-8c12-3c8217e6806b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010030643)

Change you  query to encapsulate it between square brakets

```
SELECT * FROM [User]
```

albeit I suggest you to change the name of the table

Comment: I will! Thank you very much!

Comment: Dont forget conn.Close() . All your code must be in try, and in finaly close  Dispose your conn, rdr  and cmd if not null ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do like Steve said. And a suggestion for your code:

```
        String connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data    Source=Accounts.mdb";
        OleDbConnection conn = null;
        OleDbCommand cmd = null;
        OleDbDataReader rdr = null;
        String mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [user]";

        try
        {
            conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
            conn.Open();


            cmd = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0}\n,{1}\n", rdr.GetValue(0).ToString(), rdr.GetValue(1).ToString()));
            }
            Console.Read();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.Write("Error founded: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null) conn.Dispose();
            if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
            if (rdr != null) rdr.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Indeed, but some using statements will be useful here